# SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener in ListView and ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

I have a ViewPager that contains a `ListFragment` with a `TouchListener` (SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener).  I modified the `ViewPager` like this:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private boolean pagingEnabled = true;

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    pagingEnabled = enabled;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!pagingEnabled) {
        return false; // do not intercept
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!pagingEnabled) {
        return false; // do not consume
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
  }
```

And I disable the swipe of the `ViewPager` from the `onOptionsItemSelected` in the `ListFragment` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_edit) {
        CustomViewPager vp = (CustomViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        vp.setPagingEnabled(false);
        getListView().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                    getListView(),
                    new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                removeItem(position);
                            }

                        }
                    }
            );

    getListView().setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    // Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during ListView scrolling,
    // we don't look for swipes.
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());


}
```

The swipe of the `ViewPager` is disabled but the problem that I can not running the `SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener`. 
I have tested these answers but do not work me

[Nesting Android ViewPager, Swiping ListItems inside a ListView horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257176/nesting-android-viewpager-swiping-listitems-inside-a-listview-horizontally)

[ViewPager intercepts all x-axis onTouch events. How to disable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122460/viewpager-intercepts-all-x-axis-ontouch-events-how-to-disable)

[Capture swipe to dismiss listview gestures in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840040/capture-swipe-to-dismiss-listview-gestures-in-viewpager)

Any solution? Thanks

Comment: What was the reason for th CustomViewPager? only for the swipe2dismiss?

Comment: Yes, the CustomViewPager is to disable the Paging and to try to run the Swipe2Dismiss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my error.
In this question I answer how disable onClick method in Fabric library. [Can I set custom onClick on my timeline using fabric sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933868/can-i-set-custom-onclick-on-my-timeline-using-fabric-sdk/30032805?noredirect=1#comment48207090_30032805)

The project is same the project is the same and this related error.
In this method disable views,clickable and long clickable:

```
//helper method to disable subviews
    private void disableViewAndSubViews(ViewGroup layout) { 
        layout.setEnabled(false); 
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) { 
            View child = layout.getChildAt(i); 
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) { 
                disableViewAndSubViews((ViewGroup) child); 
            } else { 
                child.setEnabled(false); 
                child.setClickable(false); 
                child.setLongClickable(false); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

and disable method to swipe2dismiss

The solution is add on list adapter this lines:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        //disable subviews to avoid links are clickable
        ViewTweetUtils.disableViewAndSubViews((ViewGroup) view);

        //enable root view and attach custom listener
        view.setEnabled(true);
        view.setClickable(false);

        return view;
    }
```

view.setEnabled only not works. You must add view.setClickable(false). Why? I don't know but it works.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should be solved in a few simple actions.

- Remove the *onInterceptTouch()* and *onTouch()* at the ViewPager, its
  not needed.
- If im not mistaken u r missing a call to *notifyDatasetChange()*
  after the for loop in the *onDismiss()*.
- Go into the SwipeTouchListener code and create a clause for direction
  so it will be enable for a ceratain direction (think about Google now
  that enable swipe only for one direction). Im guessing that u r
  enabling the swipe only for the first and last pages, if not then
  think about it becuase enabling swipe2dismiss for a middle page is a
  bad ux descion.

Comment: SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener works for me one of every thousand times. I've got the listview to detect SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener ontouch method and disable the viewpager ontouch.
The problem I have is that in the method ontouch always, or almost always, this condition is met: case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                    break;
                }
Any ideas? Thanks